# Server, laptop, router, and modem, IP addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, iptables

I have a simple server at home. The server is directly connected to the modem and has IP: 192.168.1.7

My laptop is connected to a wireless router, which is connected to the same modem. My laptop has IP 192.168.11.2.

I set up some iptables rules which only allow my own laptop IP address to connect over http (port 80) to the server. I thought I had put in the right IP address, i.e. 192.168.11.2. But my logs show that the connection is blocked because it is coming from IP 192.168.1.6. So clearly only allowing this IP address accepted the connection.

My question is why is the incoming IP address (192.168.1.6) to the server different than my laptop's IP (192.168.11.2). Is this because of the router in between? If so, how? Shouldn't the server just simply see my laptop's ip address?

Comment: Your server and laptop are connected to different devices with different subnets. You should set the router into bridge mode so it is on the same subnet as the modem.

Comment: Try the instructions on p24 of the manual http://cdn.cloudfiles.mosso.com/c85091/WHR-G300N_Manual_web.pdf

Comment: http://www.modsbyus.com/setup-a-buffalo-whr-300hp-as-a-bridge-or-repeater/

Comment: https://www.avforums.com/threads/buffalo-whr-g300n-v2-as-wireless-bridge.1292919/

Comment: if I use page 24 (basically changing the router into an access point) the situation remains the same. Flashing the router is too much work for now. I'm ok with the current situation (per my question) but I was just wondering why this behavior happen.

Comment: Ok the problem is solved. I took your advice and changed the wifi router into an access point (p. 24). However, if I had my server connected to the modem I could not communicate with it via my laptop. So I plugged the server ethernet cable into the access point and now I can communicate with it. All the devices are in the same subnet. Thanks

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the advice of DavidPostill and changed the wifi router into an Access Point (AP). My laptop (now IP 192.168.1.9) can connect to it and the internet.

However, now my laptop would not communicate with the server, probably because the server is connected directly to my modem via ethernet cable. So, instead, I plugged this cable into the access point as well. Now I can communicate with my server via my laptop (through the AP) and I know which IP to allow in *iptables*.

Answer (score 1):

Disable DHCP on router or use the router as AP only - don't use the WAN port.. use the internet cable in one of the LAN ports and the router will act as a switch ( sort of )

Comment: this is basically what DavidPostill suggested and it works